# $L_2$ projection with integer constraints and prescribed sum

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, projection, dynamic-programming

Suppose I am given a vector $v^0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and integers $k,\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Assuming $k$ is close to zero (e.g. $0\leq k\leq5$), is there an algorithm for solving the following integer optimization problem?
$$
\boxed{
\begin{array}{rl}
\min_v & \|v-v^0\|_2\\
\mathrm{s.t.} & v_i\in\{-k,\ldots,0,\ldots,k\}\ \forall i\\
& \sum_i v_i = \ell.
\end{array}
}
$$
In other words, I wish to approximate $v^0$ with a vector $v$ that sums to $\ell$ and has integer entries between $-k$ and $k$.  The $L_2$ norm here is needed.

This looks *somewhat* like an instance of the knapsack problem, but the $L_2$ norm and potentially negative entries in $v$ have me confused how to formalize this, e.g. using some sort of dynamic programming technique.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have a suitable solver (CPLEX, GUROBI, MOSEK, SCIP, many others), you can solve this as a Mixed-Integer Quadratic Program (by squaring the objective) or as a Mixed-Integer Second Order Cone Problem.

Here is code to solve it in YALMIP under MATLAB.

```
v = intvar(size(v_o))
optimize([-k <= v <= k, sum(v) == l],norm(v-v_0))
disp(value(v)) $ displays the optimal value of v
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Indeed, when $k$ is small enough you can even reduce it to an integer program rather than a quadratic objective --- my current implementation calls Mosek.  I'm really hoping to find a direct algorithm, however!